# How to put in bold only one word in Facet Plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet

I have code like this:

```
df <- read.csv("sycl_e_s.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)

df.long<-melt(df,id.vars=c("ID","Type","Annee"))

df.long$value <- gsub(" ", "", df.long$value)
df.long$value <- sub("O", "0", df.long$value)
df.long$value <- as.numeric(df.long$value)

df1 <- df 
df1$Annee <- factor(df1$Annee, levels = c("Tesla A100", "Tesla V100", "Tesla P100"))


myplot =ggplot(df.long,aes(variable,value,fill=as.factor(Annee)))+
   geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+
   ylab("Simulation Progress (%) using SYCL") +
   scale_fill_manual(values=c('#762a83', '#af8dc3', '#e7d4e8'))+
   facet_wrap(~Type,nrow=3, labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 85))


myplot + theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.title=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1),
axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

My my data is this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = 1:6, Type = c("gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000"
), Annee = c("Tesla A100", "Tesla P100", "Tesla V100", "Tesla A100", 
"Tesla P100", "Tesla V100"), Neighbor.search = c(2.7, 2, 3.2, 
7.9, 5, 10.5), Launch.PP.GPU.ops.. = c(3.3, 3.5, 4.7, 5.8, 7, 
8.3), Force = c(10.5, 9.1, 14.8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.7), PME.GPI.J.mesh = c(56.5, 
63.6, 48, 75.5, 78.1, 67.6), NB.X.F.buffer.ops = c(7.3, 5, 7.6, 
0, 0, 0), Write.traj.. = c(0.9, 1.6, 2.2, 3.5, 5.3, 4), Update = c(4.1, 
3.4, 3, 1.2, 0.4, 1.2), Constraints = c(9.6, 8.8, 12.1, 2.5, 
1.7, 3.4), Rest = c(5.2, 3.1, 4.3, 3.3, 2.3, 4.2), Wait.PME.GPU.D2H = c(8.3, 
13, 7.4, 25.2, 44, 24.3), PME.3D.FFT = c(30.3, 33.5, 26.3, 39, 
24.2, 30.8), PME.solve = c(4.5, 5.2, 4.8, 5.7, 3.8, 6), Wait.PME.GPI.J.gather = c(7.6, 
7, 3, 2.8, 4.4, 2.5), Reduce.GPI.J.PME.F = c(2.1, 1.2, 1.2, 0.5, 
0.2, 0.3), Launch.PME.GPU.ops. = c(3.4, 3.5, 4.9, 2.1, 1.4, 3.3
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
>
```

How to only have benchMEM.tpr and MD_15NM_WATER.tpr words in bold in Facet Plot? I know that to put the whole text in bold I would use this: theme(strip.text = element_text(face = "bold")) but how to put in bold only those two words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the `ggtext` package which allows for styling text via Markdown and HTML/CSS. To this end wrap the words to be displayed in bold in `**` and in case of the facet labels use `strip.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 15)`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

df.long$Type <- gsub("((benchMEM|MD_15NM_WATER)\\.tpr)", "**\\1**", df.long$Type)

myplot <- ggplot(df.long, aes(variable, value, fill = as.factor(Annee))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  ylab("Simulation Progress (%) using SYCL") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#762a83", "#af8dc3", "#e7d4e8")) +
  facet_wrap(~Type, nrow = 3, labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 85))


myplot + theme(
  strip.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 15),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  legend.title = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank(),
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
  axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
)
```

[image]